# Two server on the same ESP32 program ? ESPAsyncWebServer and ESP32WebServer

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, arduino, esp32

i am working on esp32 module, i have made a web interface to show the sensors values, using :

ESPAsyncWebServer.h library and AsyncWebServer server(80);

but now i want to add a Camera,but for this latter i have to use :

ESP32WebServer.h library and ESP32WebServer server2(80);

How can i do to use this two server in the same program please ? when i tried that, i can compilate the sript, but only the server witch begin.server() or begin.server2() is first it will work, the second no !!

i also tried to do server.end() server2.begin() to use the other server, but it does not work also (it says server2.end() does not exist for ESP32WebServer.h library)

Thank you, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run both servers on the same port (80 in this case).

The port number uniquely identifies the software on the device which will handle the data associated with that connection. You can't have two different servers on the same port.

The camera web server software probably has streaming video on port 80 embedded in it, so if you run it on a different port number parts of it will likely not work correctly.

Create the two servers on different ports:

```
ESP32WebServer server(80);   // camera software
AsyncWebServer server2(81);  // everything else
```

Then you'll access the async web server through links like:

```
http://esp-ip-address:81/path
```

Comment: thank you, i did like you suggest and it work fine now with two servers.

Comment: If it's working, please accept this answer as a solution so that other people can that it solves the problem.